# Use of explicit interface property by casting to generic type

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to call an explicit interface property by casting to a generic type. More specifically, here is the example I tried to make work:

```
public interface I1
{
    double Value { get; set; }
}

public interface I2 : I1
{
    // Hide value from I1 to use it as an explicit interface property.
    new double Value { get; set; } 
}

public class C1 : I2
{
    // Exception because I only care about I2 explicit Value property.
    double I1.Value { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    double I2.Value { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleClass<T> where T : I1
{
    public double? SomeMethod(I1 i1)
    {
        if (i1 is T t)
            return t.Value;

        return null;
    }
}

public static class Main
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var exampleClass = new ExampleClass<I2>();
        var c1 = new C1();
        ((I2)c1).Value = 1;
        exampleClass.SomeMethod(c1);
    }
}
```

If I call Main.Test(), he will throw an exception because he will try to get the I1.Value property on c1. Why is that case ? It seems to me he should cast c1 to I2, thus return the I2.Value property.

Comment: Considering that your implementation of `I2` in `C1` involves ruining `I1` by throwing an exception, `I2` really has no business inheriting from `I1`. What are you really trying to do with this?

Comment: @madreflection In my real example, I have  `C1` that implements another interface, say I3, that has the exact same code as `I2`. By specifying the generic type in ExampleClass instance, I want to pick the interface from which he will the get the Value property. Do you think I should add I3 to make the example clearer ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this `I3` has to do with things, but it sounds like what you've posted doesn't contain enough information to demonstrate the real problem you're trying to solve. Also, your comment describes the solution you're trying, not the problem you need to solve, which means this is likely to be an X/Y problem. As it stands, there's no reason that `I2` should inherit from `I1`. There's no evidence that it has any benefit and it clearly has a drawback.